# WP white screen of death after duping a site that works fine on same server

Tags: php, wordpress, subdirectory, duplication

I have simply duped a site that runs absolutely fine on a separate domain into a sub directory of another domain for development purposes. I have zipped the /httpdocs/ directory excluding cache and uploads directories (they are >4gb large) and mysqldump'ed the database. There were no errors during the import of files or database.

Worth noting, the destination domain runs a separate WP installation in a different sub directory that should not have an effect on my installation. The domain contains a non-CMS site in the root with a .htaccess file, but there's nothing striking about it - just rewrite rules and caching configuration (I have tried disabling it).

What happens is that I am presented with a blank page with no page-source.

I have tried:
- Messing up DB connection intentionally to see if I can get some sort of error.
- Turning on WP Debug and PHP error reporting (nothing).
- Increasing memory limit to 512mb
- Disabling all plugins

It seems to me that WP is just not being run by Apache?

Can anyone suggest something to try and find the root of the problem at least?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you have access to the Apache logs or config, check to verify that the vhost config is pointing to your installation directory.

Comment: You might want to post this over on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/